# textbox doesnt exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

getting an error for every textbox on the page saying that it doesn't exist in the current context on default.aspx.cs even though they are present within default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" /> 
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblTemperature" runat="server" Text="Temperature"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTemp" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="101px"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnCalc" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Calculate Score" /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblScore" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblAlert" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my default.aspx.cs each time it throws the error saying that the text boxes and labels do not exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
        int score;
        score = 0;
        //CHECK TEMP IS VALID
        double Temp;
        if (double.TryParse(txtTemp.Text, out Temp))
        { //SUCCESS
        }
        else
        {
            //FAIL
        }

        //TEMP RATE CALC
        if (Temp <= 35.0)
        {
            score = score + 3;
        }
        else if (Temp >= 35.1 && Temp <= 36.0)
        {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else if (Temp >= 36.1 && Temp <= 38.0)
        {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        else if (Temp >= 38.1 && Temp <= 39.0)
        {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else if (Temp >= 39.1)
        {
            score = score + 2;
        }

        //WriteScore
        lblScore.Text = score.ToString();


        if (score <= 1)
        {
            lblAlert.Text = "GREEN";
            lblAlert.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (score >= 2 && score <= 4)
        {
            lblAlert.Text = "AMBER";
            lblAlert.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (score >= 5)
        {
            lblAlert.Text = "RED";
            lblAlert.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }

}

}
```

Comment: Important question -> are you using a Website or a Web Application? Web Applications will have an additional Default.aspx.designer.cs file. In the meantime do you still get the problem if you drag controls from the toolbox onto the page?

Comment: web applications, as it does have the designer file

Comment: OK if you inspect the *.designer.* file can you see objects representing the  controls on the page? If not, there's your problem. You can probably fix as easily as deleting them from the .aspx page and re-adding by dragging controls from the toolbox. Let me know if that helps...

Comment: it was relatively empty, removed the old textboxes and dragged new ones from the toolbar and named them appropriately, and the issue still occurs.

Comment: How about restart your visual studio?

Comment: Still persists after a restart too, im really stumped as i had something very similar working fine

Comment: How about re-creat the file?

Comment: Have recreated in a new project , still the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox does not exist in current Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736873/textbox-does-not-exist-in-current-context)

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more text box to your Design form and this error will be resolved immediately you can delete new text box

Answer (score 0):

Try clean solution and then build again!

Comment: Still the exact same unfortunately.